# How can I select the last element of this particular php array?

Tags: php

I need to select the last element in a particular array. For example I need the last element in this array which is currently set to the forth or [3]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will return the last element of an array.

```
$last = end($categories);
echo $last['category_id'];
```

**Note:** Be mindful this also sets the internal array pointer.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I figured it was the end() command but didn't know how to use it in this particular case. Your example works perfectly.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark answers when you find one that works for you.